# How to show SpinnerList below of Button when i tapped on it in android

Tags: android, android-spinner

Hi i am new for android in my app i have created one button and one textview

when we tapped on my button i want to show spinner list and when we select any of row i want to display that data in my textview

for this i wrote below code but when we tapped on button spinner is not displays below of button

it's displaying like my below image i want to display that list below of my button please help me

### xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="15dp"
        android:paddingBottom="15dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="title" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:text="OK"
            android:onClick="ClickButton" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <Spinner
        android:layout_below ="@+id/mainlayout"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:prompt="@string/spinner_title" />

</LinearLayout>
```

### activityclass:-

```
public class SpinnerList extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] spinnerList = {"first","second","third"
    };
    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.spinner_layout);

        spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerList);
        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
        spinner.setVisibility(spinner.GONE);
    }

    public void ClickButton(View view){

        spinner.performClick();
    }
```

[image]

Comment: since button is in a linearlayout the spinner cannot get its reference.. put the button outside the linear layout

Comment: yes i kept my spinnerlist below of linearlayout but still it's not working

Comment: i want exactly display that spinnerlist below of button with same width

Comment: u want the spinner to be hidden right?? and one more thing instead of gone use INVISIBLE and also use align parent right

Comment: make ur parent layout relative layout

Comment: yes ye i want to invisible my spinner and when i tap on button i want to diaplay spinner below of button with same width

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106580/discussion-between-abhiram-and-djphy).

Answer (score 1):

[image: it looks like this]
Here you go:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/imageViewplaces"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="15dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="title"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>


<Button
    android:id="@+id/imageViewplaces"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:onClick="ClickButton"
    android:text="OK" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageViewplaces"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
     />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: showing exceptions like Error:(13, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/imageViewplaces').

Comment: ur button has to be outside the main layout

Comment: then what can we do ?

Comment: since i moved ur button outside and the textview had to align to left of the button i did that

Comment: replace the whole code of ur layout with my it is working on mine

Comment: and i have removed prompt attribute from spinner since i didnt have a resource

Comment: yes yes i replaced this code in my layout file but it's showing that exception

Comment: like Error:(13, 34) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_toLeftOf' with value '@id/imageViewplaces').

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106584/discussion-between-djphy-and-abhiram).

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout as a wrapper, rather than linearlayout to effectively achieve this. 
You can specify that spinner would remain below the button strictly by using relativelayout

Comment: hai @UMESH0492.. i guess u have a comment privelige so please comment if its not an answer

Comment: its his use case.. he wantedly has hidden it

Answer (score 0):

```
<Spinner
android:id="@+id/name_of_board_id"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:overlapAnchor="false"/>
```

Comment: android:overlapAnchor="false" ...is important to make dropdown view at bottom

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want your list below your button. if yes then I recommend you to use `PopupMenu` instead.

**Code**

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, country /* your button */);
for (int i = 0; i < spinnerList.length; i++)
    popup.getMenu().add(1, i, i + 1, spinnerList[i]);
popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // perform your task
        return false;
    }
});
```

hope this will help you somehow.